# How to Decrease Size of Cards in Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning html and css and I'm editing myself a bootstrap template. I would like to know how to put these three fields side by side on the same line.

[image]

My site:http://tratspay.com/app/rastreio.html

Current code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 m-b-4">
        <!-- Card -->

        <p class="card-text">Transportadora:</p>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>-- Selecione</option>
            <option>Correios</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 m-b-4">
        <!-- Card -->

        <p class="card-text">Número de Transação:</p>
        <fieldset class="form-group">

            <input class="form-control" id="basicInput" type="text">
        </fieldset>

    </div>
    <!-- Card -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 m-b-4">
    <!-- Card -->

    <p class="card-text">Código de Rastreio:</p>
    <fieldset class="form-group">

        <input class="form-control" id="basicInput" type="text">
    </fieldset>


    <!-- Card -->


    <div class="col-lg-3 m-b-4">
        <!-- Card -->

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</a> </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 m-t-6">

</div </div> </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: You have a div class name  "row" with two div inside "col-lg-3 m-b-4" (transportadora and numero de ...). Put Your third div "col-lg-3 m-b-4" (codigo de rastreio) inside this div class name"row".

Comment: Your code has several HTML structure issues, try to fix them then edit the question.

Comment: you seem to have some unnecessary closing divs

Comment: Put each `p` and `input` inside a `div` so you have 3 containers - 1 for each input group. Set the `width` of this div to 33% since you have 3 of them. This will make each input be 1/3 of the parent element, even if you resize the screen. If the last one is still underneath the first 2 because of other styling issues, set this `div` to have `float: left;`

Comment: Many thanks for the tips! Get it done in my code. Very happy to be part of this community!